# Is there a dataset that has average road quality by United States county?

Tags: data-request, usa, infrastructure

I can't think of a measure for road quality, exactly, but I'm looking for a dataset that ideally has some numeric value (e.g., 1 through 10, 1 being the "worst" road quality) representing the average quality of the roads in a given county in the United States. Maybe it's average prevalence of traffic delays, maybe it's the number of potholes, I'm not sure.

Is there an open dataset like this?